# using variables to direct label command in windows

Tags: windows, command-prompt

We have to set the drive label on ~800 USB drives. We have multiple Windows computers set up able to take 10 drives at a time. As there will also be some files copied, I set the drive letters once in the batch file using:

```
SET dest1=d:
SET dest2=e:
SET dest3=f:
SET dest4=g:
REM etc.
```

However, I can't seem to use

```
label %dest1% mylabel
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you try? An error message? It doesn't work? The computer reboots...(?) It works fine here.

Comment: I am on a German Windows 7 machine, the output says something like invalid volume name. I checked the variable, echo %dest1% returns d:

Comment: ah! it worked! I had used SET dest1=d:\ THANKS!

Comment: But if you try `label d: Boris` on the command line it works??? That's really odd. What about `label %dest1% Boris`?